# React-Native Modal is not rendered with a specified height and width

Tags: react-native

The Modal that I use is rendering in full screen I couldn't make it appear like a dialog box.

This is my Modal file:

```
<Modal
  visible={this.props.visible}
  animationType={this.props.animationType}
  onRequestClose={() => { console.log('Modal has been closed.'); }}
>
  <ActivityIndicator
    size={this.props.size}
    color={this.props.color}
  />
</Modal>
```

This is where I use it:

```
<View>
  <LoadingModal
    visible={this.state.loading}
    animationType="slide"
    size="large"
    color="black"
  />
</View>
```

I am getting this now when I do this and when I gave width and height to the views, later on, I removed all that since didn't get any change

[image]

What I want is this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this might help you: https://snack.expo.io/HkGhIy90-

Also, don't forget about [Dimensions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html) module, to set marginTop and marginBottom dynamically for each screen based on the its height instead of using the fixed value like in my Expo Snack.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are seeing is the default React Native behavior. You are not setting any style so why were you expecting the dialog to be centered?

Some tips:

1. If you want something centered in the middle you want to set alignItems and justifyContent to 'center'. That usually does the trick to put it in the middle of the parent view.
2. RN default setting is that everything has flex but you need to set the very first parent view to flex=1 so RN knows it needs to ocupy the whole screen.
3. By default any child of a view will be ordered in a column. Since you want to have a row, you need to set flexDirection = 'row'
4. Styles do not inherit from their parent like normal CSS. You need to set each style manually.

I recommend you read all the get started guide before doing anything else. Specially read this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html

Comment: Pls read the question carefully because I already told why I am not giving any styles **`I gave width and height and some styles to the views later on I removed all that  didnt matter to the modal`**  I left it like this `style={{ }}`  to let others know that I have tried styles before and I have clearly mentioned it in question'

Comment: And you please read carefully my answer which pretty much tells you how to solve this. Good luck.

Comment: Nah thats not the answer to solve this because I have tried that

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question.  But I've had luck making the modal transparent and setting nested views to get the effect you are looking for.

Here is an expo link with a working example: https://snack.expo.io/ByCd6FBpS.

Hopefully this is useful to someone else in the future.

Comment: Here if I not closed the modal and leave the page as it before and then If i try to open the modal window it not fets opened

Answer (score 0):

```
  <Modal
    backdropColor={'white'}
    transparent={true}
    visible={modal}>
    <View style={styles.modals}>
      <Text style={{alignSelf: 'center', width: 200, textAlign: 'center'}}>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas
        eget tempus augue, a convallis velit.
      </Text>
    </View>
  </Modal>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 modals: {
  margin: 50,
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  elevation: 5,
  borderRadius: 10,
 },
});
```

**Don't apply style to modal, just wrap all the modal content in a  and apply style to that .**